# stream_socket_sendto(): Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, sockets

I'm using Laravel. When I `dd($request->all())` that the data inside it involves file and some other data. it returns the error

> [2019-02-22 19:40:24] local.ERROR: stream_socket_sendto(): Connection
>   refused {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0):
>   stream_socket_sendto(): Connection refused at
>   /vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Server/Connection.php:63

So I got that there might be a php-fpm bad configuration. Because I'm using `Apache 2.4.6` so I can't use `Listen 127.0.0.1:9000` as I know it is only for `Apache 2.4.10` and later. So I used `listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock`. But this one can't have any port. BTW the `www.sock` file size is 0 and the its owner is root.

Is the error that Laravel/PHP returns, related to php-fpm configuration?

If yes how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most time this is not a laravel issue but php file upload size issue.
so what you need to do is to increase the upload size in php.ini file. on your terminal you can do this

```
 sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

then update this lines

```
memory_limit = 1G
upload_max_filesize = 1G
post_max_size = 1G
```

also update this file

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
memory_limit = 1G
upload_max_filesize = 1G
post_max_size = 1G
```

Don't forget to restart apache 
`service apache2 restart`
and laravel `php artisan serve`